# Prononciation de an, en, ain et in

Tags: prononciation, voyelles, nasalisation

Est-ce que il y a des distinctions entre ces différentes nasales ?

- an
- en
- ain
- in

Est-ce-que il y a des différences entre la règle et la pratique courante ?

J'entends *demain* être prononcé par certains *an* et par autres *en*.

Comment: Il faudrait distinguer d'une part "an" et "en", et d'autre part "ain" et "in".

Comment: Voir aussi cette explication ;-): http://ezinearticles.com/?Getting-to-Grips-With-French-Nasal-Vowels&id=7468426

Comment: Pour ma part, je dirais que en et in sont souvent prononcés, respectivement, comme des versions *sèches/courtes* de an et ain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Son [ɑ̃]<sup>1</sup> :

> J'en voudrai dans un an.
>   pansement
>   tente
>   tante

**an** et **en** dans ces mots en principe se prononcent pareil.
Je ne sais pas s'il existe des variantes régionales.

Son [ɛ̃] :

> pain, pin, demain
>   hein, teint, tient, tien

**ain**, **in**, **ein**, et **en** après [j] en principe se prononcent [ɛ̃] mais les variantes régionales existent. Dans le midi on a tendance a ajouter en finale le son [ŋ] après le son [ɛ̃].  Et on dira donc qu'on mange du [pɛŋ] dans le midi et du [pɛ̃] dans le nord.

Et au nord du Massif Central on a tendance à rapprocher le son [ɛ̃] du son [œ̃]. C'est à dire qu'il est parfois difficile de faire la distinction entre brun [bʀœ̃]  et brin [bʀɛ̃] quand un parisien parle.

**Édition :**

Sur la **[base audio libre de mots français](http://shtooka.net/collections/fra/fr/)** du projet *[Shtooka](http://shtooka.net/fr/)*<sup>3</sup> :  *[un brin d'herbe](http://swac-collections.org/view_sound.php?id=9635)* prononcé par un parisien (donc du nord du massif central) la différence entre le [ɛ̃] de *brin* et le [œ̃] de *brun* est à peine marquée.  Elle le serait plus par un méridional.

Ceci juste pour me donner l'occasion de faire connaître le projet *[Shtooka](http://shtooka.net/fr/)* Ça peut rendre de grands services à ceux qui veulent apprendre à prononcer le français. La région d'origine des donneurs de voix est toujours indiquée, et ce n'est pas la voix neutre et souvent synthétique des dictionnaires en ligne.

---

<sub>1. Pour l'API voir [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).</sub>

Comment: Entre `an` et `en`, voir [Why are "an" and "en" pronounced the same? Pourquoi « an » et « en » ont-ils la même prononciation?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/292) : il semble qu'il y ait une variation sur `[ɑ̃]` dans certaines régions.

Comment: La dernière fois que j'ai regardé, la Belgique se trouvait au nord du massif central et l'opposition entre [ɛ̃] et [œ̃] s'y fait à ma connaissance toujours.

Comment: Je dirais que [pɛ̃g] c'est un peu exagéré, [pɛ̃ŋ] par contre c'est proche de la réalité :-)

Answer (score 3):

pour les Méridionaux, dont je fais partie, natif de Nice, une phrase telle que : "je mange du pain sous un pin" exige 3 sons très sensiblement différents et même 4 si je comptabilise la prononciation de l'article "un". Je ne suis pas en mesure sur mon clavier d'user de symboles phonétiques, mais ( je suis musicien) j'userai de métaphores sonores : le "in" du pin, l'arbre, est un son bref, assez aigu, très nasalisé alors que le ain du pain qu'on mange est un son plus long, plus grave dans lequel il subsiste le souvenir du "a" initial  ( en contrepartie, le ein de "j'ai mal aux reins" serait un peu entre les deux précédents avec le souvenir du "e" initial, évidemment plus aigu que le son "a")

le son "un" n'a strictement rein à voir avec les précédents, mais cela est assez couramment répertorié par les études phonétiques, je n'y insiste pas .

En revanche, je signale que la nuance sonore ci-dessus entre "ain" et "ein", se retrouve assez fréquemment dans une nuance entre "an" et "en" .
Ainsi, une phrase telle que "le vent souffle dans les branches" implique que le son de "en" du mot "vent" soit musicalement plus aigu que le son "an" de branche" ( pour les musiciens, je dirais qu'il y a une seconde, voire une tierce d'écart, descendant, entre les deux) et un rien plus bref ...