# How are the nasalized vowel sounds in “enfant” pronounced?

Tags: prononciation, voyelles, nasalisation

I just started learning French, and I came across the word *enfant*. The question I have concerns this word's pronunciation.  I looked in the dictionary, and it said /ɑ̃fɑ̃/, which is supposed to sound like "amfam" ("am" as in the word *champ* and "f" as in the word *flip* or "*at*).

Is that really the correct way to say it? Whenever I hear the word in online dictionaries, I can clearly hear a hard "n" and not an "m" like in "amfam."

Comment: Your confusion comes from the fact that the combination of letters **am** (in the word *champ*) is pronounced just like the combination **an**. So **champ** and **enfant** have the same sound  /ɑ̃ /. And that is pronounced like the word *en*. If you listen to *en* on [Forvo](http://fr.forvo.com/word/en/#fr) you have the exact sound (the clearest pronunciation to me is probably the 4th one, female, French). Two good pronunciations of [*enfant*](http://fr.forvo.com/word/enfant/#fr) on that page of Forvo.

Comment: On wikipedia the list of [the various ways](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_graphies_des_phon%C3%A8mes_du_fran%C3%A7ais#.2F.C9.91.CC.83.2F) the sound /ɑ̃ / can be written in French.

Comment: 1. "am" as in "champ" is wrong and very far from the correct sound (at least if you are American -- I don't know how British people pronounce the vowel in champ). If you are American, think of a Southerner saying "aw" in "lawn." Or, better, search for french nasal vowels on youtube, where you can find lessons. 2. If you are hearing an "n" in the dictionary, something is wrong with the dictionary.

Comment: (I think the OP is referring to the English word "Champ." If OP is referring to the French word "champ" then disregard part 1 of my previous comment.)

Comment: @Laure, you should post your comment as an Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Actually to pronounce "enfant" you can put your tongue completely into sleeping mode. Don't try to pronounce any "hard n" or "m" or other consonant except for for the "f".

Other than that, what the comments under your post says is right, pronounce it like the little word "en".

Other examples of the pronunciation of both "en" and "ant" can be found in following words:

"grand" (tall)
"gens" (peoples)
"empathie" (empathy)
"France"

I hope I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble to explain how to pronounce this to my Chinese friend. I went with the following explanation:

First you have 3 nasalized vowels sound:
`an`, `on` and `in` each one derived from the vowels `a`, `o` and `è` respectively. (`en` actually pronounce very similarly to `an`, I would not do the distinction as beginner)

To pronounce the n sound you let air go trough your nose. For those you need to put the front of your mouth in the position you would to pronounce the associated vowels (`a` -> `an`, `o` -> `on` and `è` -> `in`) and arrange the back of the mouth let air go trough your nose like for `n`.

It is quite hard to explain how to do it but I hope this help.

Comment: Explaining that the sound which is written *in* comes from the vowel *i* is wrong. The *in* sound uses ɛ as base vowel (usually written *è* or *ê*). See [this answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/8343/79) for more correspondances. And by the way, Polish has similar sounds (nasalized vowels).

Comment: @St&#233;phaneGimenez thank you for the correction, answer accordingly edited.