# Pourquoi le français parisien a-t-il perdu pour la plupart la distinction entre /e/ et /ɛ/?

Tags: prononciation, linguistique, france, voyelles, accents-régionaux

Pourquoi le français parisien a-t-il perdu pour la plupart la distinction entre /e/ et /ɛ/?
C'est-à-dire la différence entre «Je le ferai» et «Je le ferais», «poignée» et «poignet», ou plus simplement é et è. Selon [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_de_France#Phonologie), ces mots sont prononcés pareils dans presque toute la France. Mais au Canada (où j'habite) il y a une différence assez solide entre les deux. Selon quel processus est-ce que la France les a combinés? Le fil [Variations sur l'utilisation de [e] et [ɛ]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/variations-sur-lutilisation-de-e-et-) est différent de ce que je veux apprendre.

Comment: Probably this question is also suited for [linguistics stackexchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Étrangement, je fais la différence à l'oral entre « poignée » et « poignet », mais pas entre « ferais » et « ferai ». Pour moi, ces deux derniers se prononcent de la même manière.

Comment: J'ai aussi noté ceci et le corollaire est que beaucoup de Français font l'erreur d'écrire le conditionnel avec la terminaison du futur.

Comment: Si c'est dans toute la France, qu'est-ce que ça a de “parisien” ?

Comment: La question devrait être « pourquoi fait-on encore la distinction dans certaines parties de la  Francophonie. Il est normal qu'elle se fasse encore au Québec où la prononciation du français est plus proche du français du 18e siècle que du français actuel.

Comment: Non non non, c'est l'accent Marseillais (et probablement plus généralement provençal)!! Nous faisons la différence à Paris. (par contre ferais = ferai)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Il n'y a pas qu'en Provence que la distinction ne se fait pas mais dans toute l'aire d'influence des dialectes occitans, ce qui doit faire une bonne moitié de la France. Mais il faut reconnaître que même en région Parisienne la différence se fait de moins en moins si on compare à il y a un demi-siècle.

Answer (score 6):

Je pense que c'est à la fois une dilution entre les accents et une facilité.
Il est très fréquent que les sons /e/ et /ɛ/ soit utilisés de façons inversée en fonction de la région d'origine. Par exemple, le **lait** (/lɛ/) se prononce parfois /le/.
La prononciation /lɛ/ est plus classique et plus éxigente, on peut donc penser que la dérive vers /le/ est un travers lié à la facilité.

Comment: Je pense que le terme de facilité n'est pas très heureux, il pourrait laisser croire à une volonté délibérée, or me si on parle de la « loi du moindre effort articulatoire » le phénomène du moindre effort est inconscient chez le locuteur.

Answer (score 3):

Toutes les langues vivantes (j'exclus donc les langues mortes et les langues fabriquées) subissent des évolutions, dans le lexique, la grammaire et  la prononciation. Une des lois qui régit l'évolution de la prononciation est celle dite  du « [relâchement articulatoire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rel%C3%A2chement_articulatoire) ».

Ce phénomène est présent dans toutes les langues, et aboutit à la disparation de l'opposition de certains phonèmes dont la différenciation n'est pas jugé pertinente dans la conversation.
Ce phénomène permet, entre autres, d'observer la modification de l'aperture de certaines paires de voyelles comme [ε] et  [e], le [ε] se refermant peu à peu, et le [e] s'ouvrant peu à peu jusqu'à se rencontrer dans un son médian.
Le même phénomène se retrouve avec l'opposition des sons [ɛ̃] et [œ̃] dont on [déjà parlé sur French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1827/358) et [a] et [ɑ] dont on a [aussi déjà parlé](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/537/358).

Ces évolutions, bien que tout à fait inconscientes au départ, une fois repérées se transmettent. C'est  à Paris, parmi les nobles de la cour, que se trouvaient les gens qui voyageaient le plus.  C'est la cour qui donnait le ton et transmettait les modes, modes qui devenaient parfois des normes.
C'est à l'aune des siècles que se mesure l’évolution, même si elle s'est accélérée depuis un siècle sous l'influence de la multiplication des moyens de communication.
De nos jours les gens se déplacent plus, et plus loin (il y a encore moins de deux siècles la majorité des gens ne sortaient pas du périmètre de leur canton) dans toutes les régions de France, ils se déracinent aussi beaucoup plus pour trouver du travail.
La radio, puis la télévision, le cinéma, l'accès à un plus grand nombre à l'enseignement secondaire (donc avec des enseignants non recrutés localement et donc n'ayant pas un accent local) ont contribué à une accélération rapide d'une certaine homogénéisation des accents et de la langue. Ce mouvement est cependant moins rapide dans les régions où survivent encore des langues régionales qui influent sur la façon dont  les natifs de ces régions parlent le français. C'est le cas dans la région toulousaine et en Provence avec l'influence de l'occitan, mais aussi en Alsace avec l'influence de dialectes d'origine germanique ou la région de Lille avec l'influence du flamand.  À Paris, où le brassage est certainement plus grand que dans le reste de la France, on a tendance a avoir une prononciation avec des différences moins marquées. Mais il est possible que les différences entre certaines prononciations « provinciales » et Paris s'amenuisent encore (échelle des siècles ?).
Les autres pays francophones n'ont pas subi les mêmes influences, et ont conservé certains sons, par exemple, en Belgique la différence entre [ɛ̃] et [œ̃], ou au Québec  la différence entre [ε] et  [e] en finale.
La prononciation [wɛ] des voyelles « oi »(le [ʁwɛ] pour le [ʁwa]), qui a commencé à disparaître en France au 17<sup>e</sup> siècle, est encore présente au Québec de nos jours, mais est connoté négativement comme marqueur social, elle est jugée « rurale ». À terme, sous la pression du « bon goût » cette prononciation risque de disparaître totalement du Québec, comme elle a disparu de France. Voir le commentaire de pantoute ci-dessous).

Comment: Par /wɛ/ tu veux dire le son qui peut se réaliser dans «moé»? Cette prononciation existe mais est stigmatisé dans la plupart du Québec. http://offqc.com/2011/03/22/moe-toe/

Comment: @pantoute **Très** intéressant. Tout à fait dans l'évolution du processus. Les communications plus faciles aboutissent à une « normalisation » et disparation des accents régionaux. Montréal impose une pression morale en déclarant ce qui est de bon goût (*refined*), bon goût qu'ils ont eux-mêmes récupérés à Paris. Cette remarque est une constatation et non pas l'expression de mes opinions.