# Variation en prononciation de "en/em " et "an/am"

Tags: prononciation, nasalisation

Les manuels de français normalement disent que "en/em" et "an/am" représentent le même son [ɑ̃] (a-nasal). Le même point est fait, par exemple, dans cette discussion: [Prononciation de an, en, ain et in](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1825/9870).

Néanmoins, mon impression personnelle (j’habite en Normandie) est que le son "en/em" est souvent plus proche de o-nasal, par exemple dans les suffixes "ment", ainsi que dans les mots comme "Barentin". (Par contre, il s'agit de clair a-nasal au début de mot, comme en *entrecôte*).

Je me demande, s'il s'agit de ma perception personnelle (je suis russophone) ou s'il existe vraiment une variation connue en prononciation (comme il en existe une dans le cas de "un/um" contre "in/im").

Comment: en et an se sont confondu très top tôt en Ancien Français, mais pas dans d'autres langues d'oil, et certaines variétés du Normand les opposent toujours. Par example p. 292 à 294 de cet article: https://www.persee.fr/doc/annor_0003-4134_1978_num_28_3_5287 traite des nasales dans les Îles Anglo-Normandes, et montre une opposition entre in [ɛ̃], en [ɒ̃ ~ ɔ̃], an [ã] et on [õ]. Certains locuteurs transposent ces oppositions dans leur français régional. Mais c'est de la pure spéculation, donc je le laisse juste en commentaire (le système des Îles n'est qu'un example, il y a d'autres distributions)